# Java passing function as parameter

Tags: java, function, generics, lambda, functional-programming

This is my first approach to lambda expressions, function as parameter or in general functional programming...

How I can call B function in this code?

```
public class Fp_example<T>
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>(asList("A"));
         new Fp_example.b_function(names, /* (1) */);
    }

    public void b_function(ArrayList<T> l, Function<T,T> func)
    {
         l.forEach( (t) -> {func.apply(t);});
    }
}
```

I need to write my function in (1), or can I write another function and just call it inside (1)?

Comment: What do you want to do, exactly?

Comment: If this is your first approach, I recommend you to go through the Oracle Java tutorials first https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html. They will teach you how to use lambda expression. You'll be able to learn more effectively this way.

Comment: I want to call a function on every element of my ArrayList. This function take a T element as input and return a T element too @PeMapModder

Comment: @MarcoCastano what does the return value do? It will get ignored in a forEach call.

Comment: Just print ArrayList element concatenate another String...It's not important what my function will do...I just wish to know how I can call and pass it...

@Tunaki thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should instantiate `Fp_example<String>`, since you are passing an `ArrayList<String>` to `b_function`.

Now, it's up to you which function to pass to the method, depending on how you wish to transform the input `String`s. Any lambda expression that takes a `String` argument and returns a `String` will do.

For example, you can pass a lambda expression that reverses the input `String`s :

```
new Fp_example<String> ().b_function(names, s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());
```

or

```
Function<String,String> a_function = s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
new Fp_example<String> ().b_function(names, a_function);
```

You might want to display the output of applying the function on the input elements, though :

```
public void b_function(ArrayList<T> l, Function<T,T> func)
{
     l.forEach( (t) -> {System.out.println(func.apply(t));});
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks man and If I want to pass a function yet defined? For example

I have a_function and b_function and  I want to call b_function like this:

b_function(names, a_function)

Comment: @MarcoCastano If `a_function` is a `Function<T,T>`, you can pass it to `b_function`.

Comment: Of course, that reversing function (`a_function`) doesn’t have any effect when being passed directly to `forEach`. For actually changing the list, you would need to use `replaceAll` rather than `forEach`, but that would render the entire method `b_function` obsolete, as you can directly invoke `names.replaceAll(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());`

Comment: @Holger That was just an example of a `Function<String,String>` that would be accepted by the OPs `b_function` method. I suggested to print the output of applying the `Function` because it doesn't mutate the List, so printing the result is the only way (beside a debugger) to see that it actually does anything.

Comment: Of course, it’s the question that started this strange usage. I still don’t get why someone who managed to pass a function to the method `forEach` asks, how to pass a function to a method.